# Sql query for group by product barcode if product has barcode and all products having no barcode

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have collection of products in which some product has barcode and some has not. So, I want to show all products which doesn't have any barcode and if any product has barcode then they will be grouped by barcode so that I can show only one.

Suppose, I have products in table like below:

```
ID    Name        Barcode  
 1    ABC         349377934434  
 2    DEF         349377934434  
 3    XYZ         NULL  
 4    XXX         NULL
```

As per above given data, My query should give only 3 products i.e 1 or 2, 3 and 4.
  What will be sql query for above condition? I want to fetch data in single query. I do not want to use loop in my code to find product for above conditions.

Please help me on this post? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, Barcode
    FROM (
        VALUES
        (1, 'ABC', '349377934434'),
        (2, 'DEF', '349377934434'),
        (3, 'XYZ', NULL),
        (4, 'XXX', NULL),
        (5, 'ABC1', '34937'),
        (6, 'DEF1', '34937'),
        (7, 'DEF2', '34937')
    )v(ID, Name, Barcode)
)

SELECT DISTINCT v.ID, v.Name, c.Barcode
FROM cte c
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ID, Name FROM cte WHERE Barcode = c.Barcode) v
WHERE c.Barcode IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT ID, Name, Barcode
FROM cte c
WHERE c.Barcode IS NULL
```

For MySQL (i don't know how to use temporary tables in MySQL, so i  create/drop simple table "temp"):

```
CREATE TABLE temp(id INT, name VARCHAR(20), barcode VARCHAR(20));
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT 1, 'ABC', '349377934434';
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT 2, 'DEF', '349377934434';
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT 3, 'XYZ', NULL;
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT 4, 'XXX', NULL;
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT 5, 'ABC1', '34937';
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT 6, 'DEF1', '34937';
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT 7, 'XYZ2', '34937';

    SELECT DISTINCT v.ID, v.Name, c.Barcode
    FROM temp c
        INNER JOIN temp v ON v.ID = (SELECT ID FROM temp WHERE Barcode = c.Barcode LIMIT 1)
    WHERE c.Barcode IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT ID, Name, Barcode
    FROM temp
    WHERE Barcode IS NULL;

    DROP TABLE temp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can we achieve this in Mysql?

Comment: Thanks. This is the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you included SQL Server in your list, here is a sample that will run there:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR(20), barcode VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1, 'ABC', '349377934434';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2, 'DEF', '349377934434';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 3, 'XYZ', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 4, 'XXX', NULL;
WITH Summary AS (
    SELECT
        ISNULL(barcode, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID())) AS barcode,
        MAX(name) AS name
    FROM
        @table
    GROUP BY
        ISNULL(barcode, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID())))
SELECT
    CASE WHEN barcode LIKE '%-%' THEN NULL ELSE barcode END AS barcode,
    name
FROM
    Summary;
```

It's pretty self-explanatory, I group by barcode, taking the top result by name where there are duplicates.  If the barcode is NULL I replace it with a random GUID, then strip these back out at the end.

Results are:

```
barcode         name
349377934434    DEF
NULL            XXX
NULL            XYZ
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can we achieve this in Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a UNION with a CTE:

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE #Products
( ID int,
  Name VARCHAR(5),
  BarCode VARCHAR(15) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Products
VALUES (1, 'ABC', '349377934434'),
       (2, 'DEF', '349377934434'),  
       (3, 'XYZ', NULL),  
       (4, 'XXX', NULL)
```

**Query:**

```
;WITH CTE
As
(
    SELECT ID, Name, BarCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By BarCode ORDER BY ID) AS RN
    FROM #Products  
    WHERE BarCode is NOT Null
)
SELECT ID, Name, BarCode
FROM #Products
WHERE BarCode is Null
UNION
SELECT ID, Name, BarCode
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1

DROP TABLE #Products
```